# Custom POI data into the Google Map

Tags: android

I have created a app and have implemented Google maps.

Am I allowed to incorporate my own custom POI data into the Google Map developing a Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add markers to the map like in the code below. You can find a full tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker).

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```